# keras.model.predict raise ValueError: Error when checking input

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I trained a basic Neural Network model on the MNIST dataset. Here's the code to the training: (imports omitted)

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data(path='mnist.npz')
x_train, x_test = x_train/255.0, x_test/255.0

#1st Define the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28,28)),     #input layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),  #main computation layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),                       #Dropout layer to avoid overfitting
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax) #output layer / Softmax is a classifier AF
])

#2nd Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#3rd Fit the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

#4th Save the model
model.save('models/mnistCNN.h5')

#5th Evaluate the model
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

I wanted to see how this model works with my own inputs, so I wrote a prediction script with help from [this post](https://medium.com/coinmonks/handwritten-digit-prediction-using-convolutional-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-with-keras-and-live-5ebddf46dc8). My prediction code is: (imports omitted)

```
model = load_model('models/mnistCNN.h5')

for i in range(3):
    img = Image.open(str(i+1) + '.png').convert("L")
    img = img.resize((28,28))
    im2arr = np.array(img)
    im2arr = im2arr/255
    im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
    y_pred = model.predict(im2arr)
    print('For Image',i+1,'Prediction = ',y_pred)
```

First, I don't understand the purpose of this line:

```
im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
```

If some one could shed light on why this line necessary, that would be of great help.

Second, this very line throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 28, 28, 1)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First dimension is used for batch size. It is added by `keras.model` internally. So this line just adds it to image array.

```
im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
```

The error you get is because a single example from `mnist dataset`, that you used for training has shape (28, 28), so as your input layer. To get rid of this error you need to change this line to

```
im2arr = img.reshape((1, 28, 28))
```